# How to set number of posts on wordpress custom post

Tags: php, wordpress, function, loops

i have made custom post in functions.php and it all works fine, but my loop shows only 9 posts. What can i do to show all of them?
loop i use:

```
<?php
            $custompost_loop = new WP_Query($custompost);
            if ($custompost_loop->have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php while ($custompost_loop->have_posts()) : $custompost_loop->the_post();
                    ?>
                    <div class="offer__single">
                        <h4 class="offer__title">
                            <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                <?php
                endwhile;
                ?>
            <?php endif;
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$custompost = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'post_type'        => 'your_post_type',
);
 $custompost_loop = new WP_Query( $custompost );
```

in your case you can add `'posts_per_page'   => -1,` to your `$custompost` array

Comment: Great, i forgot about funcions.php lol
Love you and thanks for help!